# JS merge duplicates in array into "[num]x string"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, merge

I'm sure that this already has a duplicate, but I couldn't find one because I had no idea on how to phrase this question. Basically, I have a JS array. The user can add items to it from a dropdown menu. This array is then fed into a textarea. The user can input the same value more than once. If they have two of the same string in the array, I would like to delete both and replace it with '2x string'. Also, if '2x string' and 'string' both exist, then they will be made into '3x string', etc, etc. Thanks in advance for answering. I really appreciate it. I tried to keep it as general as possible so that others with the same problem can get help from this too.

JS:

```
var newfish = 'foo';
var oldtextareacontent = 'foo';
var fish = new Array();
var fishformatted = new Array();

function addfish(){
    //form is never submitted so as not to refresh page
    oldtextareacontent = document.getElementById("stock").value;
    newfish = document.getElementById("fish").options[document.getElementById("fish").selectedIndex].text;
    fish.push(newfish);
    fishformatted = fish.join("\n");

    document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = "Your stock: &#10;&#10;" + fishormatted;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the better way to store them isn't as an array of the modified values, but keeping track of the counts. For example: `{"stringA": 2, "stringB": 9, "stringC": 1, ...}`, or  `[{value: "stringA", count: 2}, {value: "stringB", count: 9}, ...]`. It depends on how you are actually interacting with them. That way, in the HTML, you can loop over either data structure, have the raw value, and add something extra if the count is greater than 1. The benefit of using the array I proposed, is to keep a sorted order. Either way, it provides an easy way to find if one exists and update, or create

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated a bit more. The array items are chosen out of a list with thousands of choices (all species of fish).

Comment: I added the JS that I have so far. It fetches data from an html select tag and prints it into a textarea

Comment: What about 2 arrays? One with duplicates and one for the users to see